# Fire Event when finish of render dom angular 10

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have a array where there are a lot of items and it is showed on screen with a *ngFor definex on html of angular component.
It works correctly. But... Later i hace to run a code with jquery when it is ended... By, how can i know when the dom of this component of angular has finished?
One option is run the code when past X seconds but the required time is different between devices. I'm using angular 10
Thank you

Comment: AfterViewInit should be sufficient for this, https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Comment: It is usefull if the data is available when component is created but, case for example data that is getted from server... the AfterViewInit, is launched before http request is completed… so I need other way in order to know when angular finish of render elements of *ngFor.

Comment: Fetch data at the parent component and pass it to the child via Input, then you can still use AfterViewInit. Don't forget to conditionally render the child with a ngIf depending on the data.